# Python sub string

Tags: python

I have run into an odd situation while trying to find a sub string in Python.  I am aware that I should use the `in` operator.

My string looks like '(email@email.org, Name, ext)'.

When I run this in the interactive terminal, it starts to not match:

```
>>> '(foo@bar.org,' in a
True
>>> '(foo@bar.org, B' in a
False
```

I have the string exactly as the pattern is in the text I provide.  I am just curious as to why `in` isn't working once it passes the first comma?

a is:

```
Purpose: foo - bar\n\n    Server Admin: (baz@bar.org,  a f. g,  6-6405) \n\n App Owner Group: hi\n\n      App Owners: (blah, blah blah,  6-5627)\n                    (foo@bar.org,  Brian Cody,  6-5624)\n\nNotes for Alerts:\n
```

Comment: Can you show us what `a` is?

Comment: probably because your string `a` does not contain '(foo@bar.org, B'... (which is impossible to tell without knowing the content of `a`, mind you.)

Comment: @mhlester I added `a`.  I had to edit it because it has sensitive work information. I assure you that on my end, I have the exact string I need to match in `a`.  I edited here to provide some dummy information.

Comment: I get False for both. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @JackAidley We have Red Hat at work and it's version 2.4.3.  So basically ancient.

Comment: Red Hat is not a version of Python; it is a distribution of Linux. What version of _Python_ do you have?

Comment: @JackAidley 2.4.3 running on Red Hat 5.  Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Everything works as expected if a actually contains `'foo@bar.org, B'`:

```
>>> a = '(foo@bar.org, Bob, x1234)'
>>> 'foo@bar.org,' in a
True
>>> 'foo@bar.org, B' in a
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string that you provided actually has two spaces between `(foo@bar.org,` and `Brian Cody`. Therefore, your second expression will return `False` because it's looking for one and only one space.

Comment: Good grief.  Turns out the file I was provided only had one space...so I'll have to go thank my co-worker.

Comment: @squiguy - any reason for removing the "correct answer" checkmark?